# Trouble Booting Up Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, gpt

I have a 14.04 LTS CD, which I used to help to reinstall the OS over my old installation of Ubuntu.

The process was pretty standard : insert disc, boot from CD, erase existing OS and install 14.04.

Everything looked fine, and I even got the message that installation was complete.

Then, I removed the CD as prompted, and rebooted the machine. That's when things went crazy. I see the DELL logo, and then a purple border, followed by a black screen. Then, ... nothing. Ever.

I had to do multiple force reboots by holding down the power button.
Holding on to the right-shift button did not open up the Grub menu. I still get back the same purple border and black screen.

Edit : I managed to enter Grub menu by holding on to the ESC key, but I am getting the Grub error below.

```
Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
```

Subsequently, I reinserted the disc and selected the option to try Ubuntu without installing, which is how I am here now.

`sudo parted -l`

shows the following:

```
Model: ATA ST2000DM001-1ER1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32                 boot
 2      538MB   1863GB  1863GB  ext4
 3      1863GB  2000GB  137GB   linux-swap(v1)


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

The Ubuntu OS seems to be installed on `dev/sda2`, while `dev/sda1` seems to be the `/boot/efi` partition.

According to `boot-repair`,

```
GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition  Attrs   Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1                 2,048     1,050,623     1,048,576 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2             1,050,624 3,638,751,231 3,637,700,608 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sda3         3,638,751,232 3,907,028,991   268,277,760 Swap partition (Linux)
```

Edit : I reinstalled 14.04 again, and now `boot-repair` can run just fine. It says `Repair Successful`, but I am getting Grub error when I hold on to the `ESC` key when booting up :

```
Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
```

When I exit from this CLI, it says that it is not able to find a system to boot. I select `F1` to `Retry boot`, and it shows me a nice Grub menu, from which I selected the first option Ubuntu after adding the parameters `nomodeset` and `nolapic`. It then blank screened... Really not sure what is going on here.

I have tried numerous things I have read over the net over the past day, but it is still stuck at this same problem. I am no expert on this! Please help! Thank you :)!

Additional Info:

`lspci | grep VGA` returns

`VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 13bb (rev a2)`

It is a DELL Precision Tower 5810.
Pastebin for Boot Info report is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/24515152/.

Comment: @Rod Smith I have looked at that question before posting this one, and I have tried the methods stated in the answers, but none of them worked for me... So, unless people are still answering to that question, I do need to ask my own question to get answers :S

Comment: I've re-opened your question. You're probably barking up the wrong tree in your attempt to use Boot Repair; the problem sounds like your Ubuntu 14.04 lacks (working) video drivers for your hardware. Since 14.04 is three years old, I recommend you try something newer -- 16.04, and perhaps 17.04. It might also be helpful to specify your exact computer model, age, and (if you know it) video chipset information.

Comment: @RodSmith The reason why I didn't think it is a video driver issue was because... My old installation was also a 14.04, and it could render fine. I don't really understand what is going on here. In fact, I am not able too see anything either when I use the 14.04 installation disc, without first setting the `nomodeset` and `nolapic` parameters. Hilariously, this machine is only 1 month old, and it is a Dell Precision Tower.

Comment: @RodSmith I reinstalled 14.04 again, and now boot-repair can run just fine. It says repair successful, but I am getting Grub error when I hold on to the ESC key when booting up : `Minimal BASH like line editing is supported.` When I `exit` from this CLI, it says that it is not able to find a system to boot. I select F1 to retry boot, and it shows me a nice Grub menu, from which I selected the first option `Ubuntu` after adding the parameters `nomodeset` and `nolapic`. It then blank screened...

Comment: What model system and what video card/chip? Often nomodeset required until you install proprietary drivers. But if now only grub prompt, install is not correct. Did you reinstall in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode? Post link to Summary Report, so we can see details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred `lspci | grep VGA' returns `VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 13bb (rev a2)`; It is a DELL Precision Tower 5810; pastebin for Boot Info report is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/24515152/. (Will add these to edit of question.)

Comment: Your make it clear that the computer *is* launching GRUB, and (until your repair), GRUB *was* launching the kernel; the no-video problem occurs well into the kernel launch process, which makes it unlikely that Boot Repair would help. Compared to your earlier working installation, you might have a BIOS-vs-EFI issue, a kernel options issue, a proprietary-vs-standard drivers issue, etc. Since the computer is one month old, I must *strongly* advise you to abandon 14.04 in favor of 16.04.2 or 17.04. Even though you say 14.04 worked before, a newer version is more likely to work without problems.

Comment: @RodSmith "Your make it clear that the computer is launching GRUB, and (until your repair), GRUB was launching the kernel;" I am not sure I understand (how it is that I made those clear). Sorry, I don't really unds how these things work. But OK. I understand what you are advising. I will try to get 16.04 on a disc and try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather late update, my apologies.
For anybody who mind chance upon this question in the future, do note that I have solved the problem by simply upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 (replaced 14.04 entirely). Credits to RodSmith for this simple solution.

Till date, I have no idea how the machine worked with 14.04 when it first came into my possession brand new.

Thank you, @RodSmith, for your input and help.

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling ubuntu or try 
catch this keys ctrl+logokey+alt and delete+end+pagedown 
try this 2 to 5 time 
its better to reinstall 
the old version
or press del key when the computer boots up go to bios features and enable the HDD smart compatibility 
i to had this problem but this things solved it